# Play console, Internal App Sharing can't upload. "needs to be published before you can use"

Tags: google-play-console, internal-app-sharing

I tried to upload my bundle .aab file to Internal App Sharing but it keeps showing the error "the app needs to be published before you can use". My app is published in the Internal Track and I've been using it for a few months now.

Here's the error screenshot: [image]

And here's the record of all the versions I have updated to the Internal track.
[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the internal testing track is not considered publishing. Try publishing on a **closed track** instead, that should fix it.